# Arduino Output Panel Font Color Change

Tags: ide, error, arduino-ide-2

I am using Arduino IDE 2.0.3.  When compiling code if there is an error it shows on a black background with a red font, that is hard for me to read.  Can I change either the background or the font?  Looking within the IDE I don't see how and not seeing anything on the internet.  TIA

Comment: Does it help if you select another theme? You can change the theme from the preferences. Open the Preferences dialog with `Ctrl/Cmd`+`,` and choose another theme, press OK.

Comment: Wow, now I feel stupid.  Themes did not even enter my mind.  Thank you for the suggestion and thank you for not point out that my question was pretty stupid.

Comment: Great! Suppose you or anybody else wants to install additional themes into the Arduino IDE, reference [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/personal-themes/1024606/2) excellent guide. The IDE does not yet support custom themes natively, but it's possible to install them as VS Code extensions manually. For the install guide, the credit goes to [in0](https://forum.arduino.cc/u/in0).

Comment: custom themes in v2.0.3 appear to be broken ... use 2.0.1 or nightly build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you dankeboy36 for pointing out "Themes".  Fixed it right up.